# Storing PageSetup from PageSetupDialog in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to use the `PageSetupDialog` class to allow the user to modify the print layout. The problem is "remembering" the settings. When pushing a certain button, the PageSetupDialog should pop up with the stored setting. When clicking `OK`, the settings should be stored again for further usage.

I managed to store the settings to some extend using serialization of the `PageSettings` property. However, the margins are being halved each time i open the dialog and close it again.

```
using (var dialog = new PageSetupDialog())
{
    dialog.PageSettings = LoadPageSettings();
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        SavePageSettings(dialog.PageSettings);
    }
}
```

`SavePageSettings` serializes the settings to string and puts them into the registry. The PrintFileName is set to "SKIP" or otherwise the serialization will crash.

```
settings.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "SKIP";
Registry.SetValue(string.Format(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\{0}\{1}",
    Company, Software, "PrintSettings", SerialHelper.Serialize(settings));
```

The `LoadPagesettings` method uses `Registry.GetValue` and the matching Deserialize-Method. The serializer is used on multiple other occasions for other classes and works fine (simple XmlSerializer).

Using debugging i can see that the loading/saving works, but the window shows the wrong data. When i first open the PageSetupDialog, the data are as following:

[image: First run, saving changes when clicking ok]

After clicking Ok and opening the dialog again, it looks like this:
[image: Second run, loading changes from registry]

(Please excuse the use of a non-english UI-Window)

I'm using .NET 4.0 if that matters

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to say for sure what's going wrong. I would not describe the change you show here as "halved"; instead, it looks more like there is something going wrong with respect to English vs. metric conversion (i.e. converting the values when they shouldn't be). So you probably should start your investigation looking at the issue that way.

Comment: FWIW, printer settings are a bit odd; because they are closely tied to the native `DEVMODE` structure, typically I would expect a program to serialize/deserialize through the `PageSettings` and `PrinterSettings` methods that provide access to the raw `DEVMODE` data (as an `IntPtr` object), saving the binary representation instead of trying to serialize/deserialize the `...Settings` objects themselves.